# How can I position an image into a frame in Tkinter and "empty" it everytime I click on a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an EXIF viewer using Tkinter. I need to load an image, which I am already doing, but I can't position it on top of my window into a frame. I used

top_frame = Frame(root)
top_frame.pack(side=TOP)

But I don't know how to position the picture I'm loading into it.
Everytime I load an image it adds it to the view, I'd like to delete the precedent one and add the new one. And this picture must be always inside a precise frame, independently on its size.

This is how I'm visualizing it now:

[image]

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
from exifread.tags import exif

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Exif Viewer')
root.geometry('500x550')
root.iconbitmap("../icons/exif.png")


def browse_image():
    global image_object, image_loaded_label
    image_loaded_label = None
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select An Image",
                                               filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpeg"), ("png files", "*.png")))
    image_object = Image.open(root.filename)
    image_loaded = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_object)
    image_loaded_label = Label(image=image_loaded)
    image_loaded_label.pack()
    image_loaded_label.image = image_loaded



def rotate_image(direction):
    global image_object
    angle = {"left":90, "right":-90}[direction]
    image_object = image_object.rotate(angle)
    rotated_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_object)
    image_loaded_label.config(image=rotated_tk)
    image_loaded_label.image = rotated_tk #Prevent garbage collection


def get_exif():
    global image_object
    exif_data = image_object._getexif()
    for tag_id in exif_data:
        tag_name = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
        value = exif_data.get(tag_id)
        print(f"{tag_name:25}: {value}")


top_frame = Frame(root)
top_frame.pack(side=TOP)

bottom_frame = Frame(root)
bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

browse_button = Button(bottom_frame, padx=20, pady=5, text="Load image", command=browse_image)
browse_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
browse_button.pack()

rotate_left_button = Button(bottom_frame, padx=10, pady=5, text="Rotate left", command=lambda: rotate_image("left"))
rotate_left_button.pack(side=LEFT)
rotate_right_button = Button(bottom_frame, padx=10, pady=5, text="Rotate right", command=lambda: rotate_image("right"))
rotate_right_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
get_exif = Button(bottom_frame, padx=20, pady=5, text="Get EXIF", command=get_exif)
get_exif.pack(side=TOP)
exit_button = Button(bottom_frame, padx=20, pady=5, text="Exit", command=root.quit)
exit_button.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `image_loaded_label`.destroy() if you want to destroy the label. But you can't get it back.

Comment: Isn't there a way to load everytime a new image?

Comment: You can use `image_loaded_label.config(image=<new PhotoImage>)` if you just want to change the image shown. What do you mean by *load everytime a new image*?

Comment: Okay, I did it in this way: image_loaded = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_object)
    img_lbl.configure(image=image_loaded)
    img_lbl.image = image_loaded ------ img_lbl = Label(root)
img_lbl.pack()